# Fragmentmanager issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am trying to have a fragment appear when a button is pressed on the template navigation drawer. I named my fragment "BluetoothFragment".
Here is the code that I am having issues with:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_bluetooth) {
        BluetoothFragment bluetoothFragment = new BluetoothFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ConstraintLayoutforfragment, bluetoothFragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_file) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_watch_import) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_account_settings_variant) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

The line that has the error is:

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ConstraintLayoutforfragment, bluetoothFragment).commit();
```

Where the "BluetoothFragment" gives the error:

```
"Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: com.example.tferfilemanager.BluetoothFragment, required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Cheers for any help and advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Fragment fragment = new BluetoothFragment();
```

if it doesn't work also, check if `BluetoothFragment`extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: cheers mate, I didnt realise I had to change the extends code haha

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your `BluetoothFragment.java` extends `Fragment`

also remove `import android.app.Fragment;` from `BluetoothFragment.java` and replace it with

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```